# slim - unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, slim-lang

I'm using Slim for my views and have this:

```
/ = render 'alphabet'

div class="house-list" data-pjax-container="true"
  - @houses.each do |house|
    = link_to house_path(house)
      .picture
        = image_tag "http://mylink.com/150/#{house.name.to_s.parameterize}-#{house.location_1.to_s.parameterize}.jpg"
      .info
        h4 = house.name
        p = house.location_1
```

Now, It's the link_to line causing issues, if I replace that with plain `div` it is all fine but using link_to causes:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to pass a `do &block` to this `link_to` in this case:

```
= link_to house_path(house) do
  .picture
    = image_tag "http://mylink.com/150/#{house.name.to_s.parameterize}-#{house.location_1.to_s.parameterize}.jpg"
  .info
    h4 = house.name
    p = house.location_1
```

Comment: Perfect, I needed the equals but added the 'do' keyword at the end. Thanks! Will accept as answer when it lets me

Comment: You're welcome @rctneil . Keep in mind that this `do &block` works also for `image_tag`, `button_to`, etc ;-)